# How to add and existing next.js app to a visual studio solution VS 2022

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

I currently a visual studio solution with lots of diffrent projects.

I have an existing nextjs app that I want to add to the solution, so that I can using visual studio 2022 (not VS code) to develop and debug the application.

I have installed the node.js development using the visual studio installer, and now I have a new project template called.

**'From existing Node.js code'**

I also found this: http://codefoster.com/existingnode/ which looks like what I need.

I have tried to use this to add the existing next.js app to my project, but when I run the project it tried to run on localhost:RANDOMPort number and the site dosn't run.

I'm guessing that this is the correct project template to use, but I'm not sure how to configure it.

Comment: Hi, have you checked my answer, does it work on your side? :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT I'm still working on the same project but havent checked out your answer yet... but I will. - If it works I'll get back to you and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can import the ReactJS App from other place and then use VS2022 to run the App. Also include debug.

Below is the steps I do on my side:

1, Put these two files under the root directory of the project:

***reactproject1.esproj***

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.5.26-alpha">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>a9857706-c039-4a3c-8997-3f5756ae92a3</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupCommand>set BROWSER=none&amp;&amp;npm start</StartupCommand>
    <JavaScriptTestRoot>src\</JavaScriptTestRoot>
    <JavaScriptTestFramework>Jest</JavaScriptTestFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

***reactproject1.esproj.user***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup />
</Project>
```

After that, your react app will be able to run in VS2022, but still unable to debug.

If you need debug, you need to add a folder named '.vscode' under the root directory. After that, create a file named 'launch.json', this file is the configuration file for debug react app:

***launch.json***

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "localhost (Chrome)",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "type": "edge",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "localhost (Edge)",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the structure of the react app on my side:

[image]

After the above steps, you will be able to import the react app to VS2022:

[image]

[image]

And then run/debug the react app:

[image]